# Using preg_match to extract string into array between : & | characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to extract serial numbers from a string to compare for matches and thought it might be possible with preg_match, but I'm struggling with the regex.

Can anyone offer any assistance please?

Current attempt is as follows:

```
$example = "CPM-200:0123456L|CPM-100:9876543L|CJ Pro:CJP33-011";

pre_match("/\:(.*?)\|/", $example, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Currently the above spits out:

```
Array(2) {
  [0]=> string(10) ":0123456L|"
  [1]=> string(8) "0123456L"
}
```

But I actually want to have it extract to:

```
Array(0) {
  [0] => 0123456L
  [1] => 9876543L
  [2] => CJP33-011
}
```

I've never been great with the regex! I've tried various combinations and the above is the closest I've managed to get to. Need to find a decent online tutorial.

Comment: You need to use `preg_match_all()` if you want to match multiple times.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your input, I didn't realise there was a preg_match_all until rock and jiboulex mentioned it below. Not used it before, but probably will be doing so more in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this

```
:([^|]+)(?:\||$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bH6cK7/1)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
: #Match :
([^|]+) #Match anything other than |
(?:
  \| #Match | literally
    | #Alternation(OR) --> Match | or $
   $ #End of string
)
```

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/:([^|]+)(?:\\||$)/"; 
$str = "CPM-200:0123456L|CPM-100:9876543L|CJ Pro:CJP33-011"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/3cQ4QJ)**

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to change a bit your regex so that it will catch the last element as well.

And you'll have to use preg_match_all instead of preg_match to catch every result :

```
preg_match_all("/\:(.*?)(?:[\|]|$)/", $example, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = "CPM-200:0123456L|CPM-100:9876543L|CJ Pro:CJP33-011";
$array  =  str_word_count($data,1,'0123456789L ');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i += 2)
    $new_array[] = $array[$i+1];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: Please add some context around code posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = "CPM-200:0123456L|CPM-100:9876543L|CJ Pro:CJP33-011";
$array = preg_split('/[\|:]/', $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$new_array = array_diff($array,array("CPM-200","CPM-100","CJ Pro"));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);
```